# Unexpected behaviour of the XPath-axis preceding

Tags: xslt, xpath

I tried to make a list of all different values of the attribute year from the following XML

```
<Parts>
    <Part Name="S1">
        <Year year="2018" i="1"/>
        <Year year="2017" i="2"/>
        <Year year="2018" i="3"/>
        <Year year="2017" i="4"/>
    </Part>
</Parts>
```

with XSLT (with ant 1.8.2), using the axis preceding

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Year [not( @year = preceding::Year/@year)]">

        <xsl:sort select="@year" order="ascending" />
        
        year: <xsl:value-of select="@year"/> -- <xsl:value-of select="./@i"/>
        <br/><hr/>
        
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

getting the result

> year: 2017 -- 2
>
> year: 2018 -- 1
>
> year: 2018 -- 3

I don't know, why I've got two times the "2018" (it is always the first of the selected elements giving the double).

With the axis preceding-sibling I get the expected result, a list with every value once:

> year: 2017 -- 2
>
> year: 2018 -- 1

Has anybody an explanation for this behaviour? I supposed preceding and preceding-sibling giving the same result in this example.

MK

Edit: Thanks for the comments.

I use the Java SE JDK 1.7.0

In the next time I will try to replace the processor by another implementation.

Comment: Works for me with `xsltproc`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce - works correctly for me using xsltproc, saxon 9 and xalan 2.7.0

Comment: I'm getting the same wrong result using Xalan from the java install. Maybe there is some inconstancy on how this is handled between the different processors?

Comment: What processor do you have installed? (Ant will use the one which is configured system-wide).

Comment: Looks like a bug in the version of Xalan packaged in the JDK. Note that the Apache versions of Xalan and Xerces are much better maintained, and much less buggy, than the versions in the JDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last I knew, the version of Xalan packaged with the Sun JDKs was ancient and buggy. As Michael suggests, I would *STRONGLY* recommend obtaining the Apache versions until and unless Sun/Oracle fixes that.

(The XSLT processor packaged with IBM's JDKs is much less buggy -- it was being maintained in parallel with the Apache code until relatively recently, when that was replaced by a new processor written inside IBM. Alas, the IBM JDKs are not available separately; they ship only bundled with an IBM product that uses them.)